# Create a new tag using ~org-roam-insert~ whose name is part of an existing tag

Tags: org-roam

I'm using org-roam's `org-roam-insert` to insert a new tag. Currently I have two tags, `Emacs` and `EmacsLisp`, now I want to add a new tag called `Lisp`. However, I found it impossible. Here is the screenshot:

[image: org-roam-insert]

As you can see, there are no options for me to create a new tag `Lisp`. I can only select the existing tag `EmacsLisp`. Is it a bug or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Try hitting `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`) to accept the current input.

Comment: @FranBurstall Thanks it works! Can you write it down as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mild infelicity of the `ivy` completion framework you are using.

To accept the current input rather than the current candidate, hit `C-M-j` (`ivy-immediate-done`).

Alternatively, set `ivy-use-selectable-prompt` to `t` in your init and then you can simply navigate to the prompt line with, for example, `C-p` and just select it in the usual way by hitting `RET`.